# Как реализовать обычный PHP-файл на базе Docker-контейнера?

Tags: docker

Начал разбираться с Docker, но информация слишком разрозненна.

Есть обычный PHP-файл, вроде `echo "Hello, world"`. Как реализовать его на базе Docker-контейнера?

Также, как развернуть его, с помощью docker-compose? Но изначальный вопрос важнее - чтобы разобраться.

Comment: что значит " Как реализовать его на базе Docker-контейнера"? что должен делать получившийся контейнер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опишу пример, когда файл `hello.php` - консольная команда, которая должна что-то сделать и вывести `echo` обратно в консоль. В этом случае сразу же после выполнения скрипта контейнер останавливается и в следующий раз его надо запускать заново

**Построение образа и запуск контейнера, основанного на этом образе**

Файл `hello.php`

```
<?php echo "Hello, world!";
```

Файл `Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:latest

COPY hello.php /srv/
```

Чтобы запусть и посмотреть результат нужно поместить файлы в какой-либо каталог и выполнить следующие команды:

```
docker build -t hello/world .
docker run --rm hello/world php /srv/hello.php
```

**Тоже самое, но с использованием `docker-compose`**

К двум предыдущим файлам добавляем файл `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "2.1"

services:
    php:
        build:
            context: .
```

В каталоге с файлами запускаем следующие команды:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose run php php /srv/hello.php
```

**Как это работает**

Пример, конечно, вырожденный. Hello, world, всё таки =)
В обоих случаях создаётся образ, на основе [php:latest](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/), файл `hello.php` копируется внутрь образа. Далее, на основе этого образа создаётся контейнер, выполняется команда `php /srv/hello.php`. Далее работа завершается, контейнер останавливается.

```
Hello, world!
```